# mod_rewrite: Absolute path makes parameters visible on the address line

Tags: mod-rewrite

When I, in .htaccess, set

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mynews/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ http://mysite/mynews.php?a=$1&b=$3&c=$2
```

the final url address http://mysite/mynews.php?a=1&b=5&c=291 becomes visible in browser's bar. Is there a way to prevent it, make mod_rewrite show "beautiful" directory, like http://mysite/mynews/1/2/3/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
http://mysite/mynews..
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mynews/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([_0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ mynews.php?a=$1&b=$3&c=$2
```

Of course you can put absolute FILEPATH (instead of url path) like:

```
/var/www/blog/mynews.php?a=$1&b=$3&c=$2
```

Comment: Peter, thx for the answer. 
I avoid using RELATIVE url path, because in this case all scripts included in mynews.php with PHP functions include() and require() got missed, cos the php page "thinks" it is placed into several folders, which are in fact "virtual" due to mod_rewrite usage.

Comment: I also had a problem with paths to images and links in HTML, which is solved by using <base href="..."> tag. But obviously, it does not work for PHP functions.

Comment: No what you said is wrong. If your server configuration is correct it doesn't matter if you will use relative or absolute path in htaccess for PHP script.

Comment: Okay. I found that this problem might be solved if insteat of include('myscript.php') you will use include('../myscript.php') or include('./../myscript.php') etc. depending on the number of "virtual" folders.